# Using local JSON files in Ardroid vs using JSON strings

Tags: android, json

I am developing an Android app that will display a list of PDF documents. The document list is a JSON file (which is currently used in a web application).  My question is: does it make more sense to store the JSON file as an asset or store the JSON as stings in a variable in a class?  The JSON is static and I only read from the file, there's no writing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it really matters - an assets file is a little more complicated to read, but it's not a huge deal.

But it might be easier to work with - you can just replace the file, edit it in whatever external editor you want, maybe generate it automatically from some other tool. That's easier with a separate file than something that has to edit a string within a Java file or whatever, you know? Plus JSON can be awkward to work with without a nice editor checking it for you

And it makes testing easier - you can write it so you provide a different source file, have a different set of assets etc, which you can't do so easily if you hardcode the JSON.

And you'll probably get better build times if you're just modifying an external assets file - no changes to the actual code files means they don't need to be rebuilt.

Most of this stuff probably doesn't matter! Just laying out the stuff that could be a consideration - but if the string form is working out fine for you, why complicate things?